# Fabric TwitterKit on Xamarin

Tags: android, twitter, xamarin, twitter-fabric

Has anyone been able to get TwitterKit https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android to work with Xamarin Android? Fabric doesn't have a plugin for Xamarin so has anyone been able to get it to work?

Comment: Please say what you are trying to do.  Is there something you have tried, that does not work?  Your are correct that there is no Xamarin plugin for Fabric.

Comment: I am trying to get the Twitter SSO (single sign-on) to work on Xamarin Android and the only way to do it is utilizing the fabric TwitterkKit. I am not sure how to even being getting it to work on Twitter. I read through the android studio example they have on their site but that utilized their plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted twitter about this a while back (I'm in the beta) and they said that they currently do not support xamarain, however, the rep that contacted me back said they were considering it.

Answer (score 0):

I did create very rough bindings at https://github.com/phischu/Android-Twitter-Core-Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I have written two 'walkthrough' blog posts recently, on how to integrate Fabric in Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS

Focusing on Crashlytics and Answers.. but the process should be similar to get TwitterKit or Digits etc to work.

p.s. its a messy process

Android - http://www.mike-irving.co.uk/web-design-blog/?blogid=92

iOS - http://www.mike-irving.co.uk/web-design-blog/?blogid=93